# Submit a web form from terminal

Tags: forms, terminal, submit

I'm trying to automate WordPress installation by creating a script which would do all that pre-development boring stuff. So if I install WordPress on a domain, say, `http://domain.tld`, can I somehow make a script that would submit a form filling in the pre-defined username and password to the `http://domain.tld/wp-install.php`?

Comment: Yes, you can use `curl` command

Comment: Did this method of installation work well?

Comment: Yes, it went perfect. I was able to make a 1-line-command WP install. But since then I turned to Codeigniter and Laravel development, so I don't have a chance to use it any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what the wp-install.php look like, but you should be able to use curl. Something like this:

```
curl --data "username=myuser&password=mypassword" http://domain.tld/wp-install.php
```